# MSDeploy - preSync command

Tags: iis-7, msdeploy

On one of our sites we have a few videos that are viewed via html5, if someone has the website open (and streaming the video file) our web deploy fails as it cannot delete the video file in  use.

I've tried using the preSync:RunCommand attribute to stop the website so the files cannot be streamed, with the idea to bring it back up with a postSync command.

But it seems that the video files are attempted to be deleted BEFORE the preSync, as my deploy will fail with the same error (cannot delete video file). But if i make sure the video isnt being downloaded then the site is deployed and turned off as expected.

Shouldnt the PreSync command be run BEFORE the 'syncing' part?

Comment: `preSync` definitely occurs before the main `source/dest` sync. Can you post a sterilized version of your command line?

Comment: Why don't you use an additional msdeploy run to stop the application before executing the sync command?

Comment: I like this idea, thanks, i'll give it a try.